# Need a exact naming for the Doc

Tags: documentation

I'm working on User Interface Document for a client project. It's actually a mobile project. I need to give a document to the client which include all the finalized User Interfaces (only the final mobile screens, no details descriptions). So what is the best name to title this document. Is there any document standard available in the industry? Please help.

Comment: can u describe scope of the project?

Comment: Hi Zufar, we can't know what to call this document and there is no standard for titling documents about user interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

If its only screens, "UI Screenshots" is a good name.